# How you calculate the average rating per genre in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this lens dataframe. It has columns to classify genres a movie belongs to. The genre categories are column names with binary values in the rows. If a movie belongs to a genre, it has a 1 under the appropriate column and 0 otherwise. I want to calculate the average rating per genre for each user in python pandas.

```
# pass in column names for each CSV
u_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/End-User/Desktop/ml-100k/u.user', 
                    sep='|',names=u_cols, encoding='latin-1')

r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/End-User/Desktop/ml-100k/u.data', 
                      sep='\t', names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')

# Reading item file:
m_cols = ['movie_id', 'title' ,'release_date','video_release_date', 'imdb_url',
          'unknown', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children\'s', 'Comedy', 
          'Crime', 'Documentary', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 
          'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi','Thriller', 'War', 'Western']

movies = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/End-User/Desktop/ml-100k/u.item', 
                      sep='|', names=m_cols, encoding='latin-1')

# create one merged DataFrame
movie_ratings = pd.merge(movies, ratings)
lens = pd.merge(movie_ratings, users)

# I have tried this but don't know how to get the average of the ratings for each user.    
df = pd.pivot_table(lens, index = ['user_id'], 
                    columns = ['unknown', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation',
                               'Children\'s', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary',
                               'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 
                               'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 
                               'Thriller', 'War', 'Western'], 
                    values = ['rating'])
print df
```

Comment: What exactly is your question. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reshaping your dataframe from wide to long to create a *genre* column and then run result through [`pivot_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) using its `aggfunc` argument, specifically for numpy mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#...same code...

lens = pd.merge(movie_ratings, users)

genrecols = ['unknown', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation',
             'Children\'s', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary',
             'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 
             'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 
             'Thriller', 'War', 'Western']

# RESHAPE DF BY MELTING (WIDE TO LONG), SELECTING ONLY NEEDED FIELDS    
mdf = pd.melt(lens[['user_id', 'sex', 'rating'] + genrecols], 
              id_vars=['user_id', 'sex', 'rating'], var_name='genre')

# FILTER FOR VALUE = 1 AND THREE NEEDED COLUMNS
mdf = mdf[mdf['value']==1][['user_id', 'sex', 'rating', 'genre']]

# RUN PIVOTED AGGREGATION    
df = pd.pivot_table(mdf, columns = ['genre'], index = ['user_id', 'sex'], 
                    values = ['rating'], aggfunc = np.mean)

print df
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much Parfait. One more thing, how would you add a column with the sex of the user? I tried: new_df = pd.merge(df, users['sex']) but doesn't work. Really new to pandas. Need this new df format to perform a logistic regression to get sex of users from their average rating by genre.

Comment: Simply add `sex` to fields to keep in all relevant lines and then in pivot add it to `index` arg. See edit.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you once again. Really appreciated.

Comment: When I try to access the sex column to change its values from M and F to 0 and 1, I get key error      df['sex'] = df['sex'].astype('category')
df['binary_sex'] = df['sex'].cat.codes  how could I access these new columns in the df dataframe and add the binary_sex one? Thank you once again.

Comment: df.reset_index(inplace=True)  worked. Thanks again Parfait. Sorry I asked so many questions, You were an unbelievable help.